# Swift call class function from corresponding subclass in superclass function

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding

I would like to implement `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)` in a superclass, and use it in all subclasses by calling a class method on the particular subclass in the superclass at runtime.

#### MySuperClass

```
class func dummyDict() -> NSDictionary

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {

    for(key,value) in self.class.dummyDict(){
                      --------------------
                               ^
                               |
                               |
                 Get this from the corresponding subclass at runtime!

        NSLog("encoding \(value) for key \(key)")
    }

}
```

Is it possible that subclasses from `MySuperClass` access the class function `dummyDict()` at runtime ?

Comment: Not sure I caught what you mean - you want that initializer to be called from any subclass, or you want that initializer to call a base method that's overridden in subclasses (and have the correct one invoked)?

Comment: superclass does a get class and calls the subclasses dictionary

Comment: So you want to enumerate all subclasses from the base class? If yes, I don't think that's possible

Comment: Maybe I know what you mean... see my answer below

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I caught what you mean. You create a `Base` class, implementing an initializer and a class (static) function:

```
class Base {
    class func dummyDict() -> Dictionary<String, String> {
        return ["base1": "val1"]
    }

    init() {
        for (key, value) in self.dynamicType.dummyDict() {
            println("encoding \(value) for key \(key)")
        }
    }
}
```

Next you want to create subclasses, and have the initializer to call an overridden version of the `dummyDict` method. You simply have to override that method:

```
class Subclass1 : Base {
    override class func dummyDict() -> Dictionary<String, String> {
        return ["subclass1": "sub1"]
    }
}
```

Now, when you create an instance of `Subclass1`, what's printed is:

```
encoding sub1 for key subclass1
```

which is the expected output.

Note the `for` loop in the initializer is using `self.dynamicType.dummyDict()` rather than `Base.dummyDict()`. The latter always calls the class method defined in the `Base` class, whereas the former calls it in the scope of the actual class inherited from `Base`

Comment: I was trying to do the same thing but can't make it to work, since the compiler generates an error telling me that I can't use `self.dynamicType.dummyDict()` as we can't use `self` inside of an `init` method ("Use of self in delegating initializer before self.init is called"). Any idea?

Comment: Hey @AliSoftware, at least in swift 2.0 u can use the dynamicType `self.dynamicType.dummyDict()`  in the init function. Even before `init()` is called. Otherwise try to call it after `init()` if that is possible for you.

Answer (score 6):

dynamicType is deprecated in Swift 3. We must use `type(of:)`.

So Antonio's example is now:

```
class Base {
    class func dummyDict() -> [String: String] {
        return ["base1": "val1"]
    }

    init() {
        for (key, value) in type(of: self).dummyDict() {
            print("encoding \(value) for key \(key)")
        }
    }
}

class Subclass1 : Base {
    override class func dummyDict() -> [String: String] {
        return ["subclass1": "sub1"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[DELETED]

use **dynamicType** as Antonio suggested in his answer

```
class Test : NSObject {
    class func dummy() -> String { 
        return "t"
    }

    init() {
        super.init()
        println("\(self.dynamicType.dummy())")
    }
}

class Test1 : Test {
    override class func dummy() -> String  {
        return "t1"
    }
}

class Test2 : Test {
    override class func dummy() -> String  {
        return "t2"
    }
}
```

Comment: "The class() method would return AnyClass! and the Compiler wouldn't know the type at compiler time... " So? The `object_getClass()` function also returns `AnyClass!` and that's not a problem.

Comment: It doesn't. But that doesn't mean the function shouldn't exist.

Comment: I said `object_getClass`, not `objc_getClass`; and the type of the `Test` class is `Test.Type`. If you do `let cls: Test.Type = object_getClass(self) as Test.Type; println("\(cls.dummy())")` in place of your println above, it indeed works.

Comment: Anyway, when you wrote "self.class is not available in swift AFAICS -- as that would be a major problem for statically typing stuff" which sounds like you're saying the `class` method isn't available in Swift *because* its type would somehow be a problem. But I showed that `object_getClass` does the same thing and also returns `AnyClass!`, and it is available in Swift and not a problem. That shows that its type is not a problem and they *could have* made the `class` method available in Swift; they just didn't, for other reasons.