# Swift - call class function in init

Tags: swift, initialization, static-methods

How can I call a class function from an initializer? I'm looking for something that would work like:

```
class A {
  var name: String

  class func getName() -> String {
    return "first class"
  }

  init() {
    self.name = Type.getName()
  }
}

class B: A {
  var bar: String

  override class func getName() -> String {
    return "second class"
  }

  init() {
    self.bar = "bar"
    super.init()
  }
}

A().name // "first class"
B().name // "second class"
B().bar // "bar"
```

(I'm looking at class functions since they can be overwritten and called before the instance is initialized)

=== Edit ===

This question is well answered by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24711715/2054629

amusingly xcode fails to compile something like:

```
class A {
  var id: String
  class func getId() -> String {
    return ":)"
  }

  init(from id: String?) {
    let finalId = id ?? type(of: self).getId()
    self.id = finalId
  }
}
```

with: `'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized`

while just using `let finalId = type(of: self).getId()` works fine.

Comment: As [the answer here shows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40159283/2976878), use `type(of: self)`, e.g `type(of: self).getName()`

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't see that before. I was also unsure I could use `self` before finishing the initialization, but that just works.

Comment: Generally, you cannot use `self` before all stored properties are initialized, but there are some exceptions to the rule, `type(of: self)` being one of them (it's perfectly safe to use before initialisation is complete because it doesn't depend on any instance state).